# Combine multiple xml files into one final android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Say I have a layout file that I would like to use as part of another layout, how would I do that?

For example, I have a table layout at `/res/layout/table.xml`. I want to use that table as a component inside a relative layout at `/res/layout/relative_stuff.xml`. Say my relative layout is to contain the table and two buttons.

The simple case is to do the combination completely inside the `relative_stuff.xml` file. But a better case would be the ability to set the table xml programmatically: the reality is I want to choose from many different tables, for now say two tables at: `/res/layout/table_1.xml` and `/res/layout/table_2.xml`.

So basically my main layout file is `/res/layout/relative_stuff.xml`. And I want to set either of two tables inside it programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You an [re-use layouts using an include tag](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html).

For example, using your example layout/table.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”>

    <include layout="@layout/table"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you don't want to do it in XML, you can use a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to inflate your XML and add it to whatever container you are using.

```
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View tableLayout = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.table, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.layout.root_id));
rootLayout.addView(tableLayout);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will add it to my code and let you know if it works in a few minutes.

Comment: You can also use Activity's [`addContentView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#addContentView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) if appropriate. (+1, even though your first sentence isn't quite right...)

Comment: @Tanis is it possible to use Include Method for Grid Layout. If possible, how can i set the value of GridLayout using Adapter.

Comment: That sounds like a different question than the one originally asked here, so I would suggest asking a new question. Yes, you can use an `<include>` tag with a GridLayout. The process of setting an adapter does not change with an `<include>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Layout Inflator Service  to add multiple add the activity.